# Wrap function pointers in template classes

Tags: c++, classes, template, pointers

I'm working on a [C++ library for Arduino and other embedded systems](https://bitbucket.org/nwehr/kick).

I'm currently working on wrapping up function pointers and member-function pointers into two C++ template classes (function and mem_fn).

Does the following code abide by good programming practices? Does it provide enough functionality?

Since there seems to be some confusion about why I would need to write code like this, let me try to clear the air. 8-bit AVR microcontrollers don't have the same resources available to them that desktop computers do. Some of the constraints include limited RAM, limited program storage, limited compute capability, and limited feature support. Because of this, existing "standard" libraries are not well suited for embedded applications like this.

```
#ifndef kick_functional_h
#define kick_functional_h

//
// Copyright 2014 Kick project developers.
// See COPYRIGHT.txt or https://bitbucket.org/nwehr/kick/downloads/COPYRIGHT.txt
//
// This file is part of the Kick project and subject to license terms.
// See LICENSE.txt or https://bitbucket.org/nwehr/kick/downloads/LICENSE.txt
//

namespace kick {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // function
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
    class function {
        function();

    public:
        function( ReturnT (*)(ArgT...) );
        function( const function<ReturnT, ArgT...>& );

        function<ReturnT, ArgT...>& operator=( ReturnT (*)(ArgT...) );
        function<ReturnT, ArgT...>& operator=( const function<ReturnT,ArgT...>& );

        ReturnT operator()( ArgT... );

    protected:
        ReturnT (*_f)(ArgT...);
    };

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // mem_fn
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template<typename ObjectT, typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
    class mem_fn {
        mem_fn();

    public:
        mem_fn( ReturnT (ObjectT::*)(ArgT...) );
        mem_fn( const mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& );

        mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& operator=( ReturnT (ObjectT::*)(ArgT...) );
        mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& operator=( const mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& );

        ReturnT operator()( ObjectT&, ArgT... );

    protected:
        ReturnT (ObjectT::*_f)(ArgT...);
    };

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// function
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::function<ReturnT,ArgT...>::function( ReturnT (*f)(ArgT...) )
: _f( f )
{}

template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::function<ReturnT,ArgT...>::function( const kick::function<ReturnT, ArgT...>& f )
: _f( f._f )
{}

template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::function<ReturnT, ArgT...>& kick::function<ReturnT, ArgT...>::operator=( ReturnT (*f)(ArgT...) )
{
    _f = f;
    return *this;
}

template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::function<ReturnT, ArgT...>& kick::function<ReturnT, ArgT...>::operator=( const kick::function<ReturnT,ArgT...>& f )
{
    _f = f._f;
    return *this;
}

template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
ReturnT kick::function<ReturnT,ArgT...>::operator()( ArgT... a )
{
    return _f( a... );
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// mem_fn
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename ObjectT, typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::mem_fn<ObjectT,ReturnT,ArgT...>::mem_fn( ReturnT (ObjectT::*f)(ArgT...) )
: _f( f )
{}

template<typename ObjectT, typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::mem_fn<ObjectT,ReturnT,ArgT...>::mem_fn( const mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& f )
: _f( f._f )
{}

template<typename ObjectT, typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
ReturnT kick::mem_fn<ObjectT,ReturnT,ArgT...>::operator()( ObjectT& o, ArgT... a ) {
    return (o.*_f)( a... );
}

template<typename ObjectT, typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& kick::mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>::operator=( ReturnT (ObjectT::*f)(ArgT...) ) {
    _f = f;
    return *this;
}

template<typename ObjectT, typename ReturnT, typename... ArgT>
kick::mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& kick::mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>::operator=( const mem_fn<ObjectT, ReturnT, ArgT...>& f ) {
    _f = f._f;
    return *this;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Why do you wrap function pointers? What is the wrapper supposed to do differently than regular function pointers?

Comment: Why are you not using the standard library?

Comment: Also note. By putting your code on this page and asking for a code review you are effectively publishing the code under A [CC commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (see bottom of page) in addition to any licensing you specify in your code.

Comment: @nwp: I'm building a library that is as close to STL or boost API as possible. Functional classes are part of that.

Comment: @Loki Astari: As mentioned, this is mainly targeted for the AVR mcu. There is no avrlibc++.

Comment: std::function is header only and provides all the functionality you want and more.

Comment: That's a fair point. However, considering the storage constraints of most microcontrollers (sometimes only 2k), I would like to have the smallest possible footprint.

Comment: Maybe something like [uSTL](http://msharov.github.io/ustl/) is for you. Reimplementing the STL takes years and is just Yet Another STL Implementation.

Comment: Remember with headers the runtime footprint is only as large as the features you use. So you should really compare your code to similar code produced by std::function. Since std::function has been code reviewed debugged and vetted by thousands of people I bet it is actually smaller than any thing you can hand code. Now yes pulling in the C++ standard library is probably not a good idea; but using specific headers is something you should at least look at and verify before heading down the note invented here rode.

Comment: Again, that's a fair point. However, std::function does have dependencies within the standard library (however small they may be). Also, the standard library makes extensive use of exceptions, which are not supported on the AVR platform (one of many frustrations).

Comment: @nwp: I have heard of uSTL and other libraries like them. I looked into all of them a couple years ago and they all exhibited one or more of the following problems: 1.) The API deviated too much from the standard library. 2.) Depended on the use of exceptions. 3.) Weren't comprehensive enough to be useful. I certainly agree with you in that there is no point in reinventing a wheel that already rolls. However, to my knowledge, there is no C++ "standard" library that already exists that will compile on an AVR. For me, that makes the kick project indispensable.

Comment: I think exceptions are a red herring. Yest the STL uses them but in relation to std::function I don' think so. It is just a type wrapper around the thing you want to behave like a function. Any errors are going to be at compile time (where you want them).

Comment: [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) says that std::bad_function_call will get thrown if !*this == true

Comment: That does not matter. If there is a `nullptr` inside the `std::function` and you call it that is your fault. If then `std::bad_function_call` is raised and exceptions are not supported the program just dies. If you do not use exceptions and call a `nullptr` the program also just dies. I do not see the difference. In your case I would suggest replacing `throw ...;` with `while (true);` to wait for the debugger which can probably be done with one regex search-replace.

Comment: @nwp, there might be an overhead in the compiled code due to the presence of any exception. I believe we are talking micro controllers here so every byte counts and every (extra) instruction executed is one too many.

Comment: I just did a comparison using my llvm compiler. When I write just one line of code in `main()` (`function<void(void)> F( &test );`), the size of the executable using std::function is 27K. However, the exact same line of code using kick::function is 9K - less than half the size.

Answer (score 2):

**Why**

What problem do `kick::function<R, Args...>` and `kick::mem_fn<C, R, Args...>` solve? The former can be completely replaced by:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
using function = R(*)(Args...);
```

The latter on the one hand adds a better invoke mechanism, in that it's actually callable. But then it limits you to non-`const` member functions. But both can really be replaced by writing a reduced form of [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
template <typename R, typename... FArgs, typename... CArgs>
R invoke(R (*func)(FArgs...), CArgs&&... args) {
    return func(std::forward<CArgs>(args)...)
}

template <typename R, typename Cls, typename... FArgs, typename... CArgs>
R invoke(R (Cls::*func)(FArgs...), Cls& cls, CArgs&&... args) {
    return (cls.*func)(std::forward<CArgs>(args)...)
}
```

There's no SFINAE here (but you can add it easily). But this makes both of your class templates invokable the same way, so then there's really no need from the class templates.

As far as the code itself, the copy/move constructor/assignments can just be omitted since the compiler-generated ones will be correct. You can also omit the default `mem_fn()` constructor instead of making it private. The compiler will delete it for you.

**Better**

If you don't want to use `std::function<Sig>`, I suggest implementing your own. This will allow you to collapse both of your different function objects into one class template - which can then be agnostic to the use case.

```
struct C { void foo(); };
void bar(C& );

function<void(C&)> f1 = &C::foo;  // OK
function<void(C&)> f2 = bar;      // OK
```

One simple way to accomplish such type erasure is to have a `placeholder` type that you keep a pointer to, with a pure virtual function to call:

```
struct placeholder {  
    R call(Args...) = 0;
};
```

Which would then be provided by either a "any functor" holder, or a "pointer-to-member" holder, or a "pointer-to-const-member" holder, or "pointer-to-rvalue-ref-qualified-member" holder, or ... Point is, lots of partial specializations.

*This* has a use-case. Type erasure. Give me *any* callable that meets this signature. The original solution can't solve that problem.